# How to catch a process in python?

Tags: python

I'm currently making a lil' launcher for PortableMu while in an internship.

We (company and I) modeled a special mode for the Mu-Editor and we are shipping it with PortableMu so that users don't need to install Mu and/or Python to use it.

The problem of PortableMu for Windows is, that you start it with a .bat and this doesnt give you any feedback.
You click, you wait ~1-2min and maybe Mu-Editor will popup.

This is not very userfriendly.

So my duty is to create a launcher.
My launcher is a simple thing: Only lil "welcome" a picture and a button to start PortableMu. It works on my private windows10.

Now I want to add in randomly picked messages for simulating "loading" which shall stop when the Mu-Editor pops up. Simply to bridge the time

Is there a method to catch when this happens?
Alas:
Can Python catch the moment when Windows opens the task/process for Mu-Editor?
If, how?

Answer (score 0):

use the tasklist

`subprocess.Popen('tasklist').comunicate()[0]` will return all the tasks currently happening in windows, simply do this every minute or so and check for your task. There are ways to make this pass without a command window popping up, here's one that i use often

```
command =subprocess.Popen(["ping","-n","1","-w","100", str(ip)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, creationflags = 0x08000000)
reply = str(command.communicate()[0])
```